# Storing value of PHP variable in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to pass a php variable to a javascript variable(on different files).

myPHP.php

```
<?php
include'myJS.php';
$hello="Hello";
echo json_encode($hello);
```

myJS.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script>
        var data;
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.onload = function () {
            data = this.responseText;

            alert(data);
        };
        oReq.open("get", "myPHP.php", true);
        oReq.send();
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

I'm running the myPHP.php file (and not myJS.php). I'm not getting any error, however, in the variable 'data' in myJS.php file, instead of storing the value of only the PHP variable, the entire myJS.php file is getting stored. How can I avoid this and store just the variable value?

P.S. This is a sample code, I would be implementing this logic with dynamic data, so please do suggest me solutions which can work with dynamic data.

Comment: Make sure that `myJS.php` does not output anything. That includes html, text, javascript, etc.

Comment: How can I check if the variable value is being stored in the JS variable or not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, why do you include a js file? You don't seem to need it.

Comment: I have some data coming into my PHP page, which I need to store into a Javascript variable. So, in real time, I would be calling the PHP page first which would then navigate to the myJS.php file so that it can be stored in the JS variable.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, the output of your php script is returned and available in javascript in `responseText`. There - in the onload function - you can store it in a javascript variable.

Comment: I was able to store the value, however, the entire code was getting stored along with the variable value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need ajax for static data, just generate javascript:

```
<?php
$hello="Hello";
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script>
        var data = "<?php print $hello; ?>";
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

If the data is not static, and you want to use ajax, separate the files:

myJS.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script>
        var data;
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.onload = function () {
            data = this.responseText;
            alert(data);
        };
        oReq.open("get", "myPHP.php?ajax=1", true);
        oReq.send();
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Here is myPHP.php:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
{
    include('myJS.php');
}
else
{
    $hello="Hello";
    echo json_encode($hello);  
}
```

Comment: I tried the second piece of code, and it made no difference, i.e., I can still see the entire form in the alert instead of just the variable value.

Comment: @user2195963 You did something wrong. You must call myJS.html, and remove include from myPHP.php

Comment: My requirement is to call the PHP file and not the HTML file. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: @user2195963 Yes, but you'll need to pass a variable to distinguish between ajax and non-ajax calls. Look at the updated answer.